# Can't put Varnish on port 80

Tags: varnish

I have just installed **Varnish 5.2.1** on Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm following the [tutorial](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.2/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html) to try and put it on port 80, but it's not working.

I start by stopping Varnish with `sudo service varnish stop`.

Then I edit `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` to change the target port:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Then I create a `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf` to specify the port for Varnish to run on:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

And then I restart Varnish:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service varnish status
```

But when I check how it's doing with `sudo service varnish status` I see:

```
● varnish.service - Varnish HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d
           └─customexec.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2020-09-03 11:55:26 BST; 37s ago
     Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/
           man:varnishd
  Process: 20459 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256
 Main PID: 20459 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 03 11:55:24 me systemd[1]: Started Varnish HTTP accelerator.
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20459]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.15.0-115-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20462]: Platform: Linux,4.15.0-115-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20459]: Debug: Child (20474) Started
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20462]: Child (20474) Started
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20462]: Child (20474) said Child starts
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20462]: Manager got SIGINT
Sep 03 11:55:25 me varnishd[20462]: Stopping Child
Sep 03 11:55:26 me varnishd[20462]: Child (20474) died signal=15
Sep 03 11:55:26 me varnishd[20462]: Child cleanup complete
```

Varnish works fine when I run it on the default port 6081, but it keeps dying when I change the port using the steps above. I have stopped all other webservers like Apache, so there is nothing already running on port 80 that could conflict with Varnish.

I'm not sure where to go from here to debug what's going wrong. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

Instead of putting this line in `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

I use this line instead:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

The newer command is what I found in `sudo service varnish status` when it runs successfully.

I'm not sure why the official documentation doesn't include the `-j unix,user=vcache -F` part at the start, but for some reason it's a default part of the command that I need to use to make Varnish work.

Here's what they mean from the [docs](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.2/reference/varnishd.html#ref-varnishd-options):

- `-j <jail[,jailoptions]>`: Specify the jailing mechanism to use.
- `-F`: Do not fork, run in the foreground.